# How to add more fields and remove or change the text from django UserCreationForm?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Im building an django web page for a personal proyect with basic login/signUp system. My problem is that i want to add more input fields like name and lastname ando aslo modify the default text, basically to change it to another language.

Thx for the help. :c
[image: Main SignUp page]

I tried to create an CustomField but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Django provided UserCreationForm api for creating a new user with three required fields (username,password1,password2), but you can override UserCreationForm like this and can add more fields from Django's default User Model.

#### form.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

# User Signup
class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','email','first_name','last_name','password1','password2']

        widgets = {
            'username':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            # 'first_name':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            # 'last_name':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'email':forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        }
```

#### for remove a unwanted text you can iterate all form fields like this

#### HTML Code

```
<form action="" method="POST">
     {% csrf_token %}
     {% for fm in form %}
          <label >{{fm.label}}</label>
          {{fm}}
     {% endfor %}
</form>
```